# Simple Graphic won't show in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Learning HTML5 I came across a cookbook for graphing and data visualization. this is the first exercise and I can't get the graphic to show.

I tried so many things that I even copy and paste the source code to see if it worked, and it didn't D:

here is the code:
index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="01.01.canvas.js"></script>
    <title>Canvas Example</title>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="init();" style="margin:0px">

    <canvas id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

01.01.canvas.js:

```js
function init()
{
    updateCanvas();
}

function  updateCanvas()
{
    //rest of the code in the next steps will go in here
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    myCanvas.width = width;
    myCanvas.height = height;
    var height = 100

    var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "#FCEAB8";
        context.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

    var circleSize=10;
    var gaps= circleSize+10;
    var widthCount = parseInt(width/gaps); 
    var heightCount = parseInt(height/gaps); 
    var aColors=["#43A9D1","#EFA63B","#EF7625","#5E4130"];
    var aColorsLength = aColors.length;

    for(var x=0; x<widthCount;x++){
        for(var y=0; y<heightCount;y++){
          context.fillStyle = aColors[parseInt(Math.random()*aColorsLength)];
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(circleSize+gaps*x,circleSize+ gaps*y, circleSize, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
          context.closePath();
          context.fill();   
        }
    }
}
```

I expected a rectangular block filled with dots of many colors showing in the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your code is attempting to use the height variable before it is declared and initialized.

```js
myCanvas.height = height;
var height = 100
```

Just have to switch the order of those lines so that height has a valid value when you try to use it, like this:

```js
var height = 100
myCanvas.height = height;
```

[Link to working CodePen](https://codepen.io/kuehlr92/pen/XWWRaZd)